# Error al imprimir la variable valor : "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

Error al imprimir la variable "valor":

```
    public static void calculaValor{
        int aportacion=5000;
        int duracion=5;

         for(int y=1;y<=duracion;y++){
                if(y > 1){
                double valor=aportacion*(y-1);
                }else{
                double valor=0.0;   
                }
                System.out.println( valor );
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes que declarar la variable que quieres imprimir fuera del for.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es simplemente que no podrás obtener el valor de la variable valor ya que esta se evalúa dentro de los `if`.

Seguramente estas obteniendo el error:

> "Cannot find symbol"

**Los errores "Cannot find symbol" generalmente ocurren cuando se intenta hacer referencia a una variable no declarada en el código.** En este caso esta declarada pero solo puede ser usada dentro del `if`, y se encuentra fuera del alcance ("Scope") al tratar de imprimir su valor.

```
            if(y > 1){
              double valor=aportacion*(y-1);
            }else{
              double valor=0.0;   
            }
            //*Aquí NO puedes usar la variable "valor".
            System.out.println( valor );
```

---

debes declararla e inicializarla para que puedas hacer uso de ella dentro del `for`:

```
 ...
 ...
 //Declara e inicializa valor.
 double valor=0.0;

 for(int y=1;y<=duracion;y++){
        if(y > 1){
          valor=aportacion*(y-1);
        }else{
          valor=0.0;   
        }
        //Imprime valor.
        System.out.println( valor );
 }
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Las variables tienen un ámbito de acción que depende de donde se declaren. En tu caso, la declaración de `valor` sucede o bien dentro de el `if` o bien dentro del `else`, por lo que solamente podrías referenciarla desde dentro de los mismos.

Para que tu variable sea accesible desde otros lugares te conviene declararla arriba del todo.

```
int aportacion = 5000;
int duracion = 5;
double valor;

for(int y = 1 ;y <= duracion; y++) {
  if(y > 1) {
    valor = aportacion * (y - 1);
  }
  else {
    valor = 0.0;   
  }

  System.out.println(valor);
}
```